# Query with CASE condition throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a MySQL query and it's working fine, Then trying to execute same query in SQL Server but its showing error.

The query is:

```
SELECT 
    system, tst_env_name 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       system,tst_env_name, 
       CASE 
          WHEN start_hrs < end_hrs 
            THEN (start_hrs * 60 + start_mins) < 1153 AND 1153 < (end_hrs * 60 + end_mins) 
            ELSE ((start_hrs * 60 + start_mins) < 1153 AND 1153 < 1439) 
                 OR (0 < 1153 AND 1153 < (end_hrs * 60 + end_mins)) 
        END co 
     FROM tst_env_details 
     WHERE project = 'JupitorQA') sub 
WHERE 
    sub.co=0 
    AND system IN ('0', '0.0.0.581');
```

The error is

> Incorrect syntax near '<'
>   Incorrect syntax near 'co'

What I did wrong with above query?

Comment: What is full query in sql `SELECT system,tst_env_name FROM (SELECT system,tst_env_name, CASE WHEN start_hrs` seems to be portion of query.

Comment: I posted full query but not yet reflected

Comment: SELECT system,tst_env_name FROM (SELECT system,tst_env_name, CASE WHEN start_hrs<end_hrs THEN (start_hrs*60+start_mins) < 1153 AND 1153 <(end_hrs*60+end_mins) ELSE ((start_hrs*60+start_mins)< 1153 AND 1153 <1439) OR  (0< 1153 AND 1153 <(end_hrs*60+ end_mins)) END co FROM tst_env_details WHERE project='JupitorQA') sub WHERE sub.co=0 AND system IN ('0','0.0.0.581');

Comment: Please post your query in the question above. It is not a good practice posting code in comments.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have a boolean data type and so you cannot have boolean *expressions*, such as you're trying to place in your `THEN` and `ELSE` parts.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - it can return **one of several values** - but it cannot return snippets of code to include into your T-SQL statement.....

Comment: You just need to nest another case expressions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this, I considor start_hr as string you can add SomeValue like your `datatype`

```
SELECT system,tst_env_name 
  FROM (SELECT 
             system,tst_env_name, 
             CASE WHEN 
                  start_hr ='SomeValue' 
             END CASE)
```

Comment: SELECT system,tst_env_name FROM (SELECT system,tst_env_name, CASE WHEN start_hrs<end_hrs THEN (start_hrs*60+start_mins) < 1153 AND 1153 <(end_hrs*60+end_mins) ELSE ((start_hrs*60+start_mins)< 1153 AND 1153 <1439) OR  (0< 1153 AND 1153 <(end_hrs*60+ end_mins)) END co FROM tst_env_details WHERE project='JupitorQA') sub WHERE sub.co=0 AND system IN ('0','0.0.0.581');

Comment: this is my full query

Answer (score 0):

You can not write direct condition inside select clause (after then while using case) instead make it like below:

```
SELECT   stock.name,
      CASE 
         WHEN stock.quantity <20 THEN 'Buy urgent'
         ELSE 'There is enough'
      END
FROM stock
```

like this would results in error

```
select 1 = 1
```

error message:

> > Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> >
> > Incorrect syntax near '='.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you intended to treat those as boolean expressions evaluating to 0 when false.

```
SELECT 
    system, tst_env_name 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
       system,tst_env_name, 
       CASE 
          WHEN start_hrs < end_hrs 
            /* I stripped out the unnecessary comparisons */
            THEN CASE WHEN (start_hrs * 60 + start_mins) < 1153 AND 1153 < (end_hrs * 60 + end_mins) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ELSE CASE WHEN ((start_hrs * 60 + start_mins) < 1153) OR (1153 < (end_hrs * 60 + end_mins)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        END co 
     FROM tst_env_details 
     WHERE project = 'JupitorQA') sub 
WHERE 
    sub.co=0 
    AND system IN ('0', '0.0.0.581');
```